# Problem with Date type on CXF endpoint returning null

Tags: java, .net, web-services, spring, cxf

I've configured a simple CXF endpoint with spring which exposes a simple object with a java.util.Date property.
once remotely invoked with a .NET client the date property is always null.

endpoint:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="simpleService" implementor="cxf.base.SimpleServiceImpl" address="/SimpleService" />
```

.NET call:

```
    SimpleServiceClient client = new SimpleServiceClient();
    simpleObject simpleObject = new simpleObject();
    simpleObject.date = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
    simpleObject.name = "Simple Object";

    txtResult.Text = client.toString(simpleObject);
```

where toString is the exposed webservice method.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's in the marshall phase on the server-side that's has the bug. If you're not sure, then do some logging on the server-side. Also, a tcp/ip monitor can show the SOAP elements transferred. Eclipse for example has an excellent tcp/ip monitor view.

If it's a marshall bug, and you marshall with JAXB, then you must convert the `java.util.Date` value to a `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` value.

This can be done with the `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory` class.

Be sure to use the overloaded `newXMLGregorianCalendar()` method that matches your date element.

A page with good information about the different date and time XSD elements:
http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp